# Pion mass in theta vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, symmetry-breaking, pions, axion

Does the mass of the charged pion depend on the QCD vacuum angle?  I've seen it said---e.g., in [these TASI lectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.02669)---that when the quark mass matrix is real and there is a nonzero QCD vacuum angle $\theta$ then we have
$$
  m_{\pi^{0}}^{2} \propto \sqrt{m_{u}^{2} + m_{d}^{2} + 2m_{u}m_{d}\cos\theta}
\qquad
m_{\pi^{\pm}}^{2} \propto m_{u} + m_{d}
$$
This is meant to suggest that $\theta \approx 0$, since the $\pi^{0}/\pi^{\pm}$ mass difference is dominated by electromagnetic contributions.

However, I can't see why $\theta$ only affects the neutral pion.  The potential in the chiral Lagrangian
$$
  V(U) \propto \mathrm{Tr}(e^{-i\theta/2}MU + e^{i\theta/2}MU^{\dagger})
$$
with $M = \mathrm{diag}(m_{u}, m_{d})$ has a minimum at
$$
U_{0} = \begin{pmatrix} e^{i\phi} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\phi} \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\tan\phi
=
\frac{m_{u} - m_{d}}{m_{u} + m_{d}} \tan\frac{\theta}{2}
$$
So we can re-write the potential as
$$
  V(\tilde{U}) \propto \mathrm{Tr}(\tilde{M}\tilde{U} + \tilde{M}^{\dagger}\tilde{U}^{\dagger})
$$
by absorbing the phase and $U_{0}$ into $M$, and then we can expand $\tilde{U}$ in powers of the pion fields.  Since the second-order part of $\tilde{U}$ is proportional to $(\pi^{0}\pi^{0} + 2\pi^{+}\pi^{-})\mathbf{1}$, this gives
$$
  V_{\text{mass}}
  \propto
  (\pi^{0}\pi^{0} + 2\pi^{+}\pi^{-})\mathrm{Tr}(\tilde{M} + \tilde{M}^{\dagger})
$$
So it looks like all three pions should have the same mass, namely
$$
m_{\pi}^{2}
\propto
\sqrt{m_{u}^{2} + m_{d}^{2} + 2m_{u}m_{d}\cos\theta}
$$
I'm not confident that this is the right way to expand the pion fields around the minimum of the potential, but I'm not sure where I might be going wrong.  Does $m_{\pi^{\pm}}^{2}$ depend on $\theta$?  If not, do you know of a reference where this expansion is done more explicitly?

Comment: Not exactly on point but a nice five part discussion of the QCD Vacuum Angle is found at http://jakobschwichtenberg.com/demystifying-the-qcd-vacuum-part-4-physical-implications-of-theta/ (I link to part four of five). The actual value of theta is either zero or very nearly zero. https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.06272v1